# 5700G reduces refresh rate as I add displays. What limitation am I hitting here?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, integrated-graphics, amd-ryzen

I have a Ryzen 5700G and I am using an ASUS B550 motherboard with 3 video outs (2 DisplayPort and 1 HDMI). I have no dedicated video card.

I can drive three displays at the same time. And each output can successfully drive a 4K display at 60hz if it's the only display. But I cannot run 3 displays at 4K at 60hz, and the limitations I am running into are not clear to me.

I can run two 4K displays at 60hz. If I add a third display of any type, the maximum refresh rate choice for the two 4K displays drops to 30hz. Also, the resolution on the third display might be limited to something less than its maximum resolution.

Also, if I run just one 4K display at 60hz, and have two other 2K monitors connected, the max refresh rate on those 2K monitors drops from 75hz to 60hz. Or, I have to run the 4K monitor at only 50hz.

So, it's not completely shocking that nobody cares about running 3 x 4K with integrated graphics. But there is nothing in the spec of the processor or the motherboard that I see that would prevent this from happening. What is going on here? Specifically, what limits the refresh rate? And, is this correct behavior?

Comment: What is the exact model of your motherboard?

Comment: @SamForbis Pro-B550M-C-CSM

Comment: Like you, I was unable to find any documentation that contains information pertaining to the display outputs/resolutions/refresh rates. I would assume that this is a CPU/GPU limitation rather than a motherboard limitation. Perhaps getting in touch with AMD's support would be prudent. If you hear anything of substance from them, it would be great if you could post it here as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely dependant on the amount of share memory your APU can use. I suggest increasing it in the bios if it's possible and trying again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).